# PubNub usage, Swift 2.0 update "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" + "Sorted"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, pubnub

```
func client(client: PubNub, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult) {
    if message.data.subscribedChannel == self.channel {
        if let messageInfo: AnyObject = message.data.message {
            let type = (messageInfo["type"] as! String) //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            let date = (messageInfo["date"] as! String).getDateString() //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            let messageText = messageInfo["message"] as! String //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            let fileUrl: String? = type == "text" ? nil : "http://college.audio-visueel.com/" + (messageInfo["fileUrl"] as! String)
            let from: ConversationMessage.sendFromType = (messageInfo["userID"] as! String) == self.userID ? .Me : .Other //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            let image = messageInfo["userPhoto"] as! String //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            let name = messageInfo["userName"] as! String //Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
            if data[date] != nil {
                data[date]!.append(ConversationMessage(userID: messageInfo["userID"] as! String,text: messageText, from: from, personImage: image, personName: name, date: messageInfo["date"] as! String, type: type, fileUrl: fileUrl))
            } else {
                data[date] = [ConversationMessage(userID: messageInfo["userID"] as! String,text: messageText, from: from, personImage: image, personName: name, date: messageInfo["date"] as! String, type: type, fileUrl: fileUrl)]
            }
            for section in self.sections {
                self.data[section]! = sorted(self.data[section]!) { Utils.compareDateTime($0.date, with: $1.date, order: .OrderedAscending) //'sorted' is unavailable: call the 'sort()' method on the collection}
            }
            searchedSections = sections
            searchedData = data
            tableView.reloadData()
            tableViewScrollToBottom(false)
        }
    }
}
```

As i understood from PubNub updates ... i didn't understood!!! Please help me to find out what is wrong and why?
[image]

also 
    Ambiguous reference to member 'client'

```
    client.historyForChannel(channel, start: nil, end: nil, limit: 10, withCompletion: {
        (result: PNHistoryResult , status: PNErrorStatus ) -> Void in
        let messages = result.data.messages
        for message in messages {
            let date = (message["date"] as! String).getDateString()
            if !contains(self.sections, date) {
                self.sections.append(date)
                self.data[date] = [ConversationMessage]()
            }
        }...
```

but it was declared at the beginning of a program ...

```
 var client: PubNub!
```

Comment: You need to pay attention to compiler warnings. The type of `message.data.message` cannot be assumed to be a dictionary, it is `AnyObject` so indexing into it with a subscript cannot succeed. Hence the error "Ambiguous use of subscript"

In our callbacks, we name the instance of `PubNub` to be `client` so you must specify `self.client` in order to access the instance variable or rename one of the variables. That is why the compiler generates a warning. These are very straightforward compiler errors generated from coding mistakes.

Comment: You need to cast the `messageInfo` as a Dictionary if you want to access it as such. An `AnyObject` cannot be accessed like a Dictionary by default.

Comment: self.client?.historyForChannel(channel, start: nil, end: nil, limit: 10, withCompletion:
            {
            (result: PNHistoryResult , status: PNErrorStatus ) -> Void in 
}
) ... ?

Comment: Oh, yes. That comment above should silence the warning, if you want the instance variable client to be the one calling history.

Comment: But it's still not working D: What should i do next? Could you be kind to "Answer" below ... not to comment with an example/sample of code?

Comment: I can't help you with the "Ambiguous reference to member 'client'" because you need to provide context for the warning. Please provide the code around that error, that is actually why that error is generated. Even seeing the entire method would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding *Ambiguous use of 'subscript'* you have to optional cast `messageInfo` down the to the expected type

```
if let messageInfo = message.data.message as? [String:AnyObject] {
```

There are only a few cases where type annotations are really needed.

Comment: God bless you :D Thx)) Tried to delete the AnyObject type, but didn't cast D: But what is wrong with "Ambiguous reference to member 'client' " - client.historyforchannel(...)

Comment: I guess `result.data.messages` must be casted to something more specific.

Comment: Ambiguous in conjunction with the compiler means in almost all cases that the compiler cannot  infer the **exact** type of an object. Help the compiler by casting the appropriate objects to their specific types.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed sorted... like it was in swift 1.2

```
self.data[section]! = self.data[section]!.sort { Utils.compareDateTime($0.date, with: $1.date, order: .OrderedAscending) }
```

anyway client issues are left ...